# How to automatically refresh the SO Order Entry Page

Tags: acumatica

I have an SO Order Entry customization that sets an Acknowledged checkbox true for each SO line during the Action Email Sales Order/quote.
      public CRActivityList    Activity;
      public PXAction notification;
      [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Notifications", Visible = false)]
      [PXButton(ImageKey = PX.Web.UI.Sprite.Main.DataEntryF)]
      protected virtual IEnumerable Notification(PXAdapter adapter,
      [PXString]
      string notificationCD
      )
      {
        foreach (SOOrder order in adapter.Get())
        {

```
      var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
      parameters["SOOrder.OrderType"] = order.OrderType;
      parameters["SOOrder.OrderNbr"] = order.OrderNbr;
     Activity.SendNotification(ARNotificationSource.Customer,     notificationCD, order.BranchID, parameters);

      foreach (SOLine line in PXSelect<SOLine, Where<SOLine.orderNbr,    Equal<Required<SOLine.orderNbr>>>>.Select(Base, order.OrderNbr))
      {

           SOLineExt rowExt = line.GetExtension<SOLineExt>();
           rowExt.UsrAcknowledged = true;

               Base.Transactions.Update(line);
                //Base.Transactions.View.RequestRefresh();
               // SOOrderEntry grp = PXGraph.CreateInstance<SOOrderEntry>();
               // grp.Document.Search<SOOrder.orderNbr>(order.OrderNbr,  order.OrderType);

      }
      yield return order;
    }
  }
```

Everything works as expected but I have to manually refresh the page to see that the check boxes are checked.  Manually refreshing the grid does not display all checks correctly.  How can I automatically refresh the page after the process so that it displays correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually a cache clear works for me but I do not see that you are persisting your change. So a user could cancel your change without saving. If you want to make sure your flag is set and saved for the user you should save the changes and then you can use the cache clear. (however save could refresh the page too)

```
Base.Actions.PressSave();
Base.Transactions.Cache.Clear();
Base.Transactions.Cache.ClearQueryCache();
```

Try that before the return.

Comment: Brebdan, Thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately that did not change anything.  I am testing with an order that has three rows, and randomly, it might display 0-2 rows checked after email process.  Refreshing the grid manually produces the same results.  Refreshing the whole page displays all rows with the box checked.  Using the arrow keys to go back one order and then returning shows all boxes checked.

Comment: Try Base.Document.Cache.Clear();   Alternatively I have used Base.Actions.PressCancel() to refresh a page. Could try this after your PressSave.

Comment: Brendan, Thanks again but no dice.  I think my problem is that I cannot refresh the order when I am in the Action.  I am going to submit a case

Comment: Brendan, Ruslan informs me that the reason the page will not refresh is that there is a bug.  A fix request has been placed to have it corrected in a future buld.  Thanks for your help.  The answers you gave should have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling in the very end of action delegate:

```
Base.Transactions.View.RequestRefresh();
```

When post back is received, PXGrid only synchronize current record, not repainting/refreshing other rows.

Comment: Ruslan, I placed the RequestRefresh at the end of the notification action.  I also tried it before and after the yield return and at the end of the for each SOLine and for each SOOrder just to be absolutely sure.  I am getting the same results, that is, no refresh unless I do so manually

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet below sets an Acknowledged checkbox true for each SO line during the action Email Sales Order/Quote. Unfortunately the Details grid did not automatically refresh due to an issue with ReportProcessor.ProcessReport(Report definition) method corrupting PXLongOperationState and UI thread BLC state. **The issue is currently resolved in the latest 6.00.1686 build.**

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Objects.AR;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PX.Objects.SO
{
    public class SOOrderEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<SOOrderEntry>
    {
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Notifications", Visible = false)]
        [PXButton(ImageKey = PX.Web.UI.Sprite.Main.DataEntryF)]
        protected IEnumerable Notification(PXAdapter adapter, [PXString] string notificationCD)
        {
            foreach (SOOrder order in adapter.Get())
            {
                var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                parameters["SOOrder.OrderType"] = order.OrderType;
                parameters["SOOrder.OrderNbr"] = order.OrderNbr;
                Base.Activity.SendNotification(ARNotificationSource.Customer, notificationCD, order.BranchID, parameters);

                foreach (SOLine line in Base.Transactions.Select())
                {
                    SOLineExt rowExt = line.GetExtension<SOLineExt>();


             rowExt.UsrAcknowledged = true;
                Base.Transactions.Update(line);
            }
            Base.Save.Press();

            yield return order;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: The fix is now available with latest 6.00.1686 build.