# Acumatica checkbox won't update on field value change

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom DAC field bound to a checkbox, but when I update the value of the field within code:

```
SOOrderExtension orderExt = PXCache<SOOrder>.GetExtension<SOOrderExtension>(row);
orderExt.UsrSignatureRequired = true;
```

the checkbox check is not updated on the UI. First I tried adding this line in the FieldUpdated event because this has worked for me before:

```
Base.Document.Update(row);
```

That didn’t work. Then I tried a suggestion I found on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40771550/how-to-automatically-refresh-the-so-order-entry-page) that forces a save and cache refresh, but my row (SOOrder) can’t save yet due to some validation rules, so that didn’t work. I think I need some kind of callback to the client to tell the UI to update itself, but usually this happens through events of bound fields. Suggestions?

Using v6.10.1219

Comment: From where you are trying to update(set true) the checkbox? If you want to update Checkbox when modifying another field on Screen, make sure that the field has  'CommitChanges=true' so it triggers evenHandlers.

Comment: I am updating the value in another field's FieldUpdated event handler.  When that value changes, I want to check the checkbox according to its value.  The event is being triggered successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colleague suggested I use cache.SetValueExt<>() instead:

```
cache.SetValueExt<SOOrderExtension.usrSignatureRequired>(row, true);
```

and now it’s updating the checkbox check for me.  SetValueExt must perform the callback on its own somehow. I guess I need to remember to use each of these methods in the appropriate situation.